# R shiny uploading a pdf from local drive does not work

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

I am trying to upload a pdf to shiny. If the pdf file is from the Internet, the following code works well:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        h5("use case - embed a pdf user guide in the app - embed as a local pdf or from web URL")
      ), 
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          # using iframe along with tags() within tab to display pdf with scroll, height and width could be adjusted
          tabPanel("Reference", 
              tags$iframe(style="height:800px; width:100%; scrolling=yes", 
                          src="https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf")),
          tabPanel("Summary"),
          tabPanel("Plot")
        )
      ))

  ),
  server = function(input, output,session){}
))
```

However, when I tried to upload a pdf saved in Desktop, which is also the working directory, I cannot see the pdf file. I used `src="example.pdf"` to replaced the web file link. As suggested by some other StackOverflow posts, I saved the pdf file in a folder named `www`, but it still not working. 
The system is MacOS X El Capiton and safari browser. I am not sure if that makes any difference.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is your code where you upload the file and try to display it? You should include your code that doesn't work so we can help you fix it.

Comment: To be clear, I only replace ```src ="https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf"``` with ```src="example.pdf"```. Everything else is the same. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you doing the upload? That `src=` is relative to the client, not the server. You need someway to "serve" your PDF up via your application.

Comment: I realize that if we split the above code to server.R and ui.R ( see [link]:(https://gist.github.com/aagarw30/d5aa49864674aaf74951) ), put the example.pdf file in a `www` folder and `src="example.pdf"` works. In this case, ui.R and server.R are the two files in the working directory with the `www` folder, which contains the example.pdf file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options. The first one: just put your file example.pdf on a /www directory where your app file is. The second: use the `addResourcePath` function before running your app to make a local directory accessible.

`addResourcePath("pdfs", "c:/temp/mypdfs")`

later use it as

`src="pdfs/example.pdf"`